# Proof of "Japanese Theorem" -- Triangulation of Cyclic Polygon

Tags: combinatorics, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangulation

On Mathoverflow, I saw this great result on the "Japanese Theorem".

- [“Japanese Theorem” on cyclic polygons: Higher-dimensional generalizations?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165168/japanese-theorem-on-cyclic-polygons-higher-dimensional-generalizations)
- Given triangulation of a cyclic polygon, the sum of the <del>areas</del> inradii of the incircles of the triangles is independent of the triangulation.

How do we prove this result that make the independents of the triangulation obvious.

[image]

The [inradius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle#Relation_to_area_of_the_triangle) is related to the area by $\boxed{\text{Area} = \text{semiperimeter} \times \text{inradius}}$.  Perhaps this can be used to re-create the conservation law above?

Also, it is sufficient to prove this result for a cyclic quadrilateral and compare the two triangulations.

---

**Proof**:  Wikipedia says is based on [Carnot's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot%27s_theorem): $OO_A+OO_B+OO_C = R + r$, where $r$ is the inradius, and $R$ is the circumradius, $OO_A,OO_B,OO_C$ distances to the sides of the triangle.

[image]

In that case, I am not understanding proof of this Carnot's result, or why - if we sum over the triangles in the triangulation - this sum is independent of the triangulation.

Comment: Perhaps you should give a link to the proof you are finding objectionable...

Comment: Note that here $OO_A$ etc. carries a sign, so the inner terms get canceled.

Comment: At least it is enough to consider tha case of a quadrilateral.

Comment: @MaMing Ok, so insides cancel?  And we get $(\# \text{sides} ) \times (\text{circumradius}) +   \sum_\Delta (\text{inradus} ) = \sum \overline{OA}_i$.  We still have to prove Carnot's result.  Maybe using [Barycentric coordinates](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/Bary_full.pdf)?

Comment: With Carnot's theorem the "Japanese Theorem" becomes obvious, since all $n-2$ triangles of the triangulation have the same circumcircle.

Answer (score 2):

To prove Carnot's result, you can turn it to a purely trigonometric identity.

First
$$
\sum OO_A=R\sum \cos A
$$
Second $r(a+b+c)=2Rr(\sum \sin A)=2 \times Area=ac\sin B=4R^2\Pi\sin A $, so
$$
r=2R\frac{\Pi\sin A}{\sum\sin A}.
$$

Now applying the well-known identities
$$
\sum \sin A=4\Pi\cos\frac{A}{2}
$$
and 
$$
\sum \cos A=1+4\Pi \sin \frac{A}{2}
$$